# Run macro and sub in access from vbscript

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have a VBScript and need to run a macro and insert data into a table. To run the macro I create an `Access.Application` object and use the `Run` function:

```
Dim oAccess
Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(accessFile)

oAccess.Run macroName
```

Now I need to insert some records and to do that I need to use an `ADODB.Connection` and `Recordset`. However normally I would call `Connection.Open` but the database is already open from the `Access.Application`. Is there a way to not have to open the Access file twice and instead get the `ADODB.Connection` from the `Access.Application` object?

Answer (score 1):

`oAccess.CurrentProject.Connection` is an `ADO Connection` for the database which is currently open in that `oAccess` session.

Use that `Connection` directly, or `Set` an object variable to it:

```vb
Dim cn
Set cn = oAccess.CurrentProject.Connection
```